# Acessing Pictures folder on XOOM honeycomb

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb, photos, xoom

getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES) on XOOM returns /mnt/sdcard/Pictures. How do I return the path to the "Pictures" folder? I would like to access the Pictures folder on the XOOM itself. When I use Settings->Storage->"Pictures,Videos" and open with Gallery I am presented with the Folders in the Pictures folder on the XOOM and sdcard.

When I try to create a cursor using the following code: managedQuery( MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.INTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, img, null, null, MediaStore.Images.Thumbnails.IMAGE_ID + "");

It returns zero records as there are no thumbnails on sdcard. I have pictures and thumbnails in the "Pictures" directory on the XOOM itself. I can see them when I connect with a USB. So how do I change the above code or use other code so that it is pointing to the public "Pictures" folder on the XOOM itself. I cannot find any documentation on this.